# Visual Studio 2013 IntelliSense Subword Navigation and Completion

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense, camelcasing

I am curious if VS2013 has the possibility to make it's intellisense auto-complete a little more effective.

I am used to have classes like `MyClassInCamelCase` and `MyClassAgainInCamelCase` even `MyClassYetAgainInCamelCase`. The way intellisense works for me is that I type <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> and I get a list of the 3 possible classes that match this word. But things will be a lot easier if I could make it like a command prompt and hit some special key that will autocomplete the word until the next CamelCase word, so I could get "My", then "MyClass" and then the next character I type can define a unique word (or just hit ; for example and auto-complete the current selected word on the list).

Also, the possibility to navigate between CamelCase words will be of great help.

Does anyone knows if this is a hidden feature or something? Or if there are external plug-ins that can make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This might not directly answer your question, but note that with camel-cased type names, you can do better than to start typing the beginning of a type name (<kbd>M</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>):

#### Typing an enclosed part of the name:

- <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> will suggest `MyClassAgainInCamelCase` and `MyClassYetAgainInCamelCase`.
- <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> will suggest just `MyClassYetAgainInCamelCase`.

#### Typing just the capitalized letters:

- <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> will suggest `MyClassYetAgainInCamelCase`.

Both of these shortcuts can be combined, btw.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but +1 for the typing images...how do I make these in my post?

Comment: @mFeinstein: Stack Overflow Markdown supports the `<kbd>` markup element; e.g. `<kbd>Any</kbd>` for the famed "Any" key. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I think the hotkey combination is Ctrl + Space to open Intelisense, than Tab, Enter or Space to insert.
There is a complete word option in the Intelisense settings, check if that's toggled on.

Comment: That's for displaying intellisense, I am asking about CamelCase subword navigation and completion